# I am looking for a specific Call of Cthulhu scenario that involves Yog-Sothoth

Tags: product-identification, call-of-cthulhu

Sometime in the past I've read a scenario, that I would like to find again. What I remember about the scenario, is that it involved Yog-Sothoth, and a theater.

I think (but I am not 100% sure), that the hook for the scenario is that a friend of the investigators falls down a ladder in the theater, and the investigators start looking into the matter. I think the conclusion is that in the basement of the theater, a cult to Yog-Sothoth operates.

Comment: Well, it's not _Shadows of Yog-Sothoth_... I just checked.

Comment: "Cthulhu" and "theaters" always make me think of The King in Yellow, but I'm not familiar with that RPG or any scenarios featuring the play. Also, I think that story relates to another Great Old One, whose name doesn't quite spring to mind...

Comment: In the meantime, I found the adventure, it is named Sound and Light and it is featured in the core rulebook of Cthulhu D20. By the way, I also find Hastur more relevant for a theater settings, so I changed that part of the adventure when we played it:)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai You can self-anser your question if you like, and accept the answer. These comments are ephemeral and might get cleaned out at some later point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the meantime, I found the adventure, it is named Sound and Light and it is featured in the core rulebook of Cthulhu D20